# What is the difference between "Willkür" and "Willkürlichkeit"?

Tags: difference

Duden Online states for *[Willkür](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Willkuer):*

> die allgemein geltenden Maßstäbe, Gesetze, die Rechte, Interessen anderer missachtendes, an den eigenen Interessen ausgerichtetes und die eigene Macht nutzendes Handeln, Verhalten

However, it does not even list the word *Willkürlichkeit.* From my point of view, I can not see a difference between those two. Are they synonymous?

---

Duden online schreibt für *Willkür* [Folgendes](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Willkuer):

> die allgemein geltenden Maßstäbe, Gesetze, die Rechte, Interessen
>   anderer missachtendes, an den eigenen Interessen ausgerichtetes und
>   die eigene Macht nutzendes Handeln, Verhalten

Das Wort *Willkürlichkeit* kann ich jedoch nicht über die entsprechende Suchfunktion von Duden finden. Persönlich sehe ich die beiden als Synonyme an ... Sind sie es?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there's a very subtle difference that is almost intangible, but I'm trying to convey my thoughts anyway.

In short words: *Willkür* refers to *a willful choice*. The derived adjective *willkürlich* roughly corresponds to *willful* (in the sense of being *headstrong* — *eigensinnig* in German that is). And the yet derived substantive *Willkürlichkeit* expresses the presence of *willfulness*.

Elaborated answer:

*Willkür* consists of *Wille* and *Kür* (cf. [Canoonet](http://canoonet.eu/wordformation/willk%C3%BCr:N:F)). The word *Kür* express that you (can) act on your own decision. In sports competition, for example, there are figures or exercises that you must do (*Pflicht*) and some that you can add (*Kür*). There's the saying "Nach der Pflicht kommt die Kür". Also, the verb *küren* means *wählen*.
As such, you decide on your own what you do and, by that, you push through your will. *Willkür*.
You find more detailed information about it in [Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GW21666#XGW21666).

So, a decision that only covers your will but doesn't consider other people involved is, thus, called a *willkürliche Entscheidung* (by turning it into an adjective), or you'd say "Die Entscheidung war reine/schiere Willkür".

It's commonly used with reference to politics and anything related to the state. *Staatliche Willkür*, *politische Willkür*, *polizeiliche Willkür*, *Willkür von Behörden*, *Willkür des Königs*. It's usually used in a negative sense, and words like *Ungerechtigkeit* are used in relation to it.

Anyway, for the comparison to *Willkürlichkeit*, what you need to remember is that *Willkür* addresses the decision of someone; or the fact that someone made a particular decision based on their will.

*Willkürlichkeit*, in contrast, refers to the presence of *Willkür*, or the fact that a person tends to exercise *Willkür*. *Die Willkürlichkeit einiger Beamten*, *zur Willkürlichkeit neigen*, *Willkürlichkeit ist (nicht) auszuschließen* are a few possible collocations. You can, though, often interchange the words without changing your statement.

This word is also defined in [Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GW21681#XGW21681). You'll find a few further examples there.

Here's a made-up example using both words in contrast to each other.

> Die Willkür seiner Entscheidung spiegelt die Willkürlichkeit so mancher machthabenden Personen dar.

---

Besides, *Willkür* is used in mathematics and natural science, and it is also a medical term.

Comment: *The derived adjective* willkürlich *means* willful. – No. *Willful* means something along the lines of *vorsätzlich* or *absichtlich.* There is no good translation of *willkürlich,* but *arbitrary* comes rather close. “He shot people willfully.” and “Er schoss willkürlich auf Leute.” mean two different things. Also note that *willkürlich* has a broader range of meaning than *Willkür.*

Comment: @Wrzlprmft "a willful child" — This word has more than one meaning. In that sense, it's rather "eigensinnig" but this is ultimately the same as "willkürliche Entscheidungen treffen".

Answer (score 4):

Observation: by appending *-lich* you transform a substantive to an adjective. By appending *-keit* you apply the backward transformation, so you have nothing gained, but lost some conciseness.

There are examples, where you arrive at a different meaning, since the starting substantive has a well-established different meaning, as in:

- Freund, freundlich, Freundlichkeit
- Hof, höflich, Höflichkeit

but I can't recognize that in your example. From Google hits I would conclude, that *Willkürlichkeit* is a technical term from linguistics with little applicability elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

Der Duden gibt zur Bedeutung von *[willkürlich](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/willkuerlich)* an:

> 1. a. auf Willkür beruhend
>      b. nicht nach einem System erfolgend, sondern wie es sich zufällig ergibt
> 2. (besonders Biologie) vom eigenen Willen gesteuert; bewusst erfolgend; gewollt

*Willkürlich* ist also mehr als die Summe seiner Teile *(Willkür + lich)* und hat zusätzliche Bedeutungen, nämlich 1b und 2. Diese sind zum Teil fast gegensätzlich zur Bedeutung 1a.

So kann ich zum Beispiel schreiben:

> 30 von 100 willkürlich ausgewählten Passanten befürworteten den Rücktritt des Bürgermeisters.

Hier impliziert der Kontext Bedeutung 1b. Wenn ich jedoch schreibe:

> 30 von 100 mit Willkür ausgewählten Passanten befürworteten den Rücktritt des Bürgermeisters.

dann impliziert dies, die in der Frage angegebene Bedeutung von *Willkür,* also dass ich die Passanten nicht nach wissenschaftlichen Maßstäben (also möglichst zufällig), sondern nach egoistischen Gesichtspunkten (zum Beispiel, um ein bestimmtes Ergebnis zu erhalten) ausgewählt habe.

Möchte ich jetzt ein Substantiv aus *willkürlich* bauen, dass die Bedeutungen 1b oder 2 erfasst, muss ich auf *Willkürlichkeit* zurückgreifen, da *Willkür* diese Bedeutungen nicht erfasst:

> Die Willkürlichkeit, mit der die Umfrageteilnehmer gewählt wurden, garantierte ein möglichst repräsentatives Ergebnis.

Hingegen ergibt der folgende Satz nicht wirklich Sinn:

> Die Willkür, mit der die Umfrageteilnehmer gewählt wurden, garantierte ein möglichst repräsentatives Ergebnis.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrarit%C3%A4t) is *Willkürlichkeit* a property of an object that was created by *Willkür.*

That leads to the assumption that they are not equal but related.

---

Laut [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrarit%C3%A4t) is *Willkürlichkeit* eine Eigenschaft einer Sache, die durch *Willkür* entstanden ist.

Dies führt zu der Annahme, dass beide nicht synonym zu verwenden sind.

Answer (score 1):

Nur mein eigenes Gefühl...

Wir reden von der Willkür zum Beispiel eines Herrschers und seiner Handlungen. Diese Handlungen nennen wir dann willkürlich, aber ich würde den Herrscher nicht willkürlich nennen. Daher ist dann auch Willkürlichkeit nur auf seine Handlungen, nicht aber auf ihn anwendbar.